# Writing a google test for class which needs windows handle

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a class whose init method needs a handle

```
bool MyClass::init(void* pWnd, void* pDC)
{
    /*
        HDC m_hDC{ nullptr };
        HWND m_hWnd{ nullptr };*/

    if (!m_hDC) // if it was not initialized
    {
        m_hWnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(pWnd);
        m_hDC = GetDC(m_hWnd);
    }

    assert(m_hWnd == reinterpret_cast<HWND>(pWnd));
    assert(m_hDC != reinterpret_cast<HDC>(pDC));

    if (!m_hDC) // if the initialization failed
    {
       return false;    // invalid parameters
    }

    .....
}
```

I am writing a google test for this class. Is there any way to mock the window handle in google test or create a dummy window handle?

Comment: What is the point of mocking window handle here?

Comment: This is a legacy code. This function is mix of logic and rendering part. I thought i can avoid the rendering part and cover the logic part

Comment: Then you'll need to separate those parts. And actually still test both of them.

Comment: i wanted to create a dummy handle without changing the original code

Comment: I believe the correct way to handle this would be to access all GDI functions via an injected interface, which can then be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the right approach but may help someone. Luckily, the library I am testing had, [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/). So I created the window using that.

Here is the code,

```
glfwInit();
// Set all the required options for GLFW
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

// Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(100, 100, "TestWindow", nullptr, nullptr);

HWND val = glfwGetWin32Window(window);
obj.init(val, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to go here is to mock calls to the external 3rd-party functions such as `GetDC`.

There are a few ways to do this:

Extract this kind of calls into one or more interfaces, depending on what makes more sense, consulting the SOLID principles and the interface segregation principle in particular. After you extract the external calls into an interface, which would be something like this in this case:

```
class SystemGateway {
    public:
        virtual HDC GetDC(HWND hwnd) = 0;
};
```

You use a dependency injection design pattern(not a framework): you take in `SystemGateway` in a constructor or use a setter method to set your `SystemGateway` in the class:

```
bool MyClass::init(std::unique_ptr<ISystemGateway> SystemGateway, void* pWnd, void* pDC) 
{
    // all of your code respectively;
}
```

Then instead of directly calling system's `GetDC`, you call `SystemGateway`'s `GetDC` method.

For production, you write the class that calls actual system's GetDC method:

```
class SystemGatewayProduction {
    public:
        virtual HDC GetDC(HWND hwnd) {
              return ::GetDC(hwnd);
        };
};
```

And for testing purposes, you write mock class that does whatever you want it to do:

```
class SystemGatewayMock {
    public:
        virtual HDC GetDC(HWND hwnd) {
              return 0;
        };
};
```

Then you test your business logic and expected behavior because you control all the variables.

This this approach works to test most of the business logic, it doesn't allow to  test all of the production code. We'll still have bare-bones classes such as that `SystemGatewayProduction` class that does calls to the system functions. How do you test those, then?

The other way that also allows to test this kind of `SystemGatewayProduction` class but also allows to test the function you originally asked about: `bool MyClass::init(void* pWnd, void* pDC)`: linker substitution or link seam: same thing, 2 different names.

What is it and how does it work? So in this case you `#include <Windows.h>` in your class header or cpp. In order for this to work, you'll need to separate your tests from the production project. In the production project you link actual .dll: `User32.dll`(that's where the `GetDC` function is defined). In the test project, however, you make it so the test project does not link the `User32.dll`. Exactly how to do this depends on your build system.

Now you'll get a linker error that it can't find function definitions **for all the functions** that were defined in the `User32.dll` that  are used in files that you included in your testing project. It could be all the files from the production project, or it could be just this one file that you're trying to test, depending on your setup.

Now you just need to define those functions in your testing project, in our case we only have one:

User32Mock.h:

```
HDC GetDC(HWND hwnd) {
    return 0;
};
```

Now in your test project in your `MyClass::init` method, it will call your mock `GetDC` method defined in the `User32Mock.h` file, and in your production project it will call actual Windows' method.

This technique is nicely described in 2 books that I know of: Modern C++ Programming with Test-Driven Development Code Better, Sleep Better by Jeff Langr and Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers.

Michael Feathers' chapter about this technique is available for free here: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417

No, I'm not paid by anyone for referencing or linking any of this. Just where I found useful information and these solutions myself when I was trying to test classes that do system calls.

The third option in this situation is to hook the `GetDC` function in your test code and redirect the execution to your mock implementation. You then do whatever you want as in previous 2 cases. There are libraries for this, such as Microsoft Detours: https://github.com/microsoft/Detours

The third option might feel like a hack at first, but in my experience it nets you the exact same results as the second option with less files that you need to sustain, less code you need to write, less setup that you need to do for your projects than the second option. You just hook only specific functions that you need in specific fixtures or even specific tests, and then unhook it at the end of the fixture or test, and let all other tests use the actual function, depending on your needs.

Of course, if there's no hooking library for the platform on which you execute your tests, then the third option is out of the question.

You might decide to use a mixture of those methods: extract the interfaces, and then decide that you want to test those production classes that do system calls, and use second or third methods.